# Target .Net Framenwork 4.8 - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

He instalado el .Net Framenwork 4.8 sdk pero al hacer un proyecto en mi Visual Studio 2013 solo me deja seleccionar hasta el 4.5.

He revisado e instalado (creo que todo) pero no consigo que me aparezca la opción.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Tengo Windows 8 y Visual Studio 2013.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Tienes algún problema en instalar Visual Studio 2019 y crear el proyecto?

Comment: Hola Rafael, muy buenas...
La licencia que tengo adquirida es visual studio 2013, no tengo inconveniente en actualizar, miraré el precio. De todas formas porque me lo comentas? solo ha esa solución?
Graaaaacias

Comment: Hola Rafael, buenas de nuevo.. Pone que visual studio 2019 comunity es gratuito... voy a probar...gracciasssss

Comment: Exactamente, las versiones Community de Visual Studio son gratuitas y perfectamente funcionales. Si lo vas a usar para uso particular, no tendrás ningún problema de licencias. Aún así, si tienes una licencia de 2013, por que no has consultado a Microsoft directamente?, ellos te deben dar soporte (va en el precio).

Comment: Gracias Rafael... Instale el visual studio 2019 comunity y en efecto se me ha solventado el problema ue tenía. Imagino que para 2013 habrá una solución pero bueno, de momento voy a seguir con el 2019 a ver que tal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final instale el Visual Studio 2019 Comunity.
Y se me resolvió el problema.
Gracias